# Jquerymobile dialog using mobile.changepage doesn't work on second page

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog

I have a dialog (not external html), which is displayed when I click on a button on the page, it works fine if the html containing the dialog is the first page to be accessed , but if that file is opened by clicking on an href from another page, the dialog doesn't show up when I click the button.

Here is the code for the page containing the dialog ...  The alert in the click event of the button is showing up even when this is the not the first page to be accessed, but the dialog doesn't show up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create Team</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Page starts here -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header" id="hdrMain" name="hdrMain"
            data-nobackbtn="true">
            <h1>Test screen</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="contentMain" name="contentMain">
            <div id="fullnamediv" data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="fullname" id="fullnameLabel" name="fullnameLabel">Team
                    Name*</label> <input id="fullname" name="fullname_r" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div id="submitDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
                <a id="buttonSave" name="buttonSave" href="#" data-role="button"
                    data-inline="true">Save</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- contentMain -->
        <div data-role="footer" id="ftrMain" name="ftrMain"></div>
        <script>
            $("#page1").bind("pagecreate", function() {
                $('#buttonSave').click(function() {
                    alert("aaaa");
                $.mobile.changePage('#successdiv', {
                    transition: 'pop',
                    reverse: false,
                    changeHash: true
                });
                    alert("after change");
                    return true;
                });
            });
        </script>

    </div>
    <!-- page1 -->

    <div data-role="dialog" data-theme="a" id="successdiv">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="f">
            <h1>Error</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>This is Page 2</p>
            <button type="submit" data-theme="e" name="successok"
                value="submit-value" id="successbutton">Close Dialog</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page ends here -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just for clarification, you have an external page and it has a link to the #successdiv page, which does not open as a dialog?

Comment: No, let us say the above page is secondpage.html and i have another page which is firstpage.html.  I first access firstpage.html in the browser and it has a href to secondpage.html (a normal href, not a dialog or anything).  And within secondpage.html (above code) when I click on the button "buttonsave" it should open the dialog "successdiv". This works (dialog shows up) fine if I open up secondpage.html directly and then click on the button. But if open firstpage.html, then click on the href for secondpage.html, then click on the buttonsave (on secondpage.html) then the dialog doesnt show up.

Comment: So it's clear. You define your dialog HTML code in the secondpage.html. When you navigate to the secind page from the first jQuery Mobile loads the very first page element (div with data-role="page") from the secondpage.html. So the element `#successdiv` is not loaded and is not present one the page. Hense nothing to show you as a dialog.

Comment: Oh ok, does it mean I cannot keep the div for dialog in the secondpage.html, does it have to be in the first page itself? If that is the case, then it is sort of unclean because I need to keep the div code of a dialog which needs to be in secondpage.html in the first page itself...and all such dialogs for all other pages will need to be defined in the firstpage.html..

Comment: @dfsq - Based on your pointer, I googled a bit and found another thread which suggests rel="external" attribute in the href in the firstpage.html which points to secondpage.html which seems to work for me, but I guess I will miss the animation and stuff ....Thanks for your help, if you write your suggestion as a separate post I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You use jQuery Mobile v1.0 but at the same time you pass incorrect arguments to `$.mobile.changePage` like if it were say v1.0 alpha. Not sure if it solves your problem but worth trying:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#successdiv', {
    transition: 'pop',
    reverse: false,
    changeHash: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, tried this, no luck, same behavior, dialog won't show up. There is no error in the javascript console and the behavior is same on chrome / firefox / android browser, it works just fine if I access this page first and then click on the button.

Comment: Did you try pass an object instead of a string as the first argument? Like `$.mobile.changePage($('#successdiv'), {...});`.

Comment: Yes, still no luck, and I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_trigger' of undefined" in the javascript console.

Comment: @saj-and Sounds like your object might not exist. Try checking $('#successdiv').length.

Answer (score 1):

When I jump from one jquery mobile page to another via a hrefs, I have to set the rel attribute to external, like this:

```
<a href="page2.html" rel="external">page2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

dfsq is right, only the div[data-role="page"] is loaded when you link to this page from another page. I'd suggest moving the dialog into its own html file and opening it either via

```
<a href="your_dialog.htm" data-role="dialog">open dialog</a>
```

or

```
$.mobile.changePage('your_dialog.htm', {role: 'dialog', transition: 'pop'});
```